# Aplicar una misma función a varios ids sin duplicarla

Tags: javascript

el nivel de preguntas que hago puede resultar básico, pero me limito a copiar, aplicarlo y una vez que funciona modificarlo.

Tengo una función que quiero aplicarla a varios `id`, es sobre mostrar texto al seleccionar una casilla de un listado `type radio`. 
Como esta en el HTML es como les muestro. Hay un archivo `.js`  y otro `.css`  que

Es la siguiente

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var $radBtn = $("span.ef-example-3-rating input:radio");
        $radBtn.click(function() {
            var $radChecked = $(':radio:checked');
            $("#para").text('')
                .append.($radChecked.val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

los `input` son así

Una serie con un id es asi:

```
   <input type="radio" class="ef-example-2-rating-input" id="ef-example-2-rating-input-2-1" name="ef-example-2-rating-input-1" value="hello">
```

Y otra serie es asi: ( esta es la que esta acriva ahora con la.funcion mencionada)

```
  <input type="radio" class="ef-example-3-rating-input" id="ef-example-3-rating-input-3-1" name="ef-example-3-rating-input-1" value="hola">
```

La ubicación del texto es en :

```
    <p id="para"></p>
```

y el texto mostrado es el siguiente

hola

Agradezco su interés por resolver el caso.

Saludos

Comment: Para alcanzar un grupo de elementos y aplicar una función a todos ellos debes agruparlos de alguna manera. La forma de *agrupación* más común es asignarle una misma clase.  Puede ser también por tipo de elemento (`radio` en este caso),  pero solamente si se trata de todos los `radio` del DOM. O una combinación de clase con tipo de elemento, o name con tipo de elemento.

Comment: Hola, esa es una cuestion, pero que la ubicación del texto ahora con id="para" ,tiene que ser un id de ese tipo para c/u o el mismo ubicado después de cada grupo es identificado como el correspondiente?

Comment: No entiendo bien tu comentario. Si te refieres a poner el mismo ID a varios elementos queda descartado, es una mala práctica y prohibido explícitamente por W3C

Comment: Aun no entiendo realmente que quieres hacer si ir agregandole al elemento #para los valores de todos los input:radio seleccionados o que???

Comment: Hay un listado de opciones : 1  -  2   -   3            muestra el valor del selenconado abajo: "Hola "  (esta ahora se muestra donde  yo sitúe el id=para )  otra parte de la misma pagina   otro listado de opciones  a- b - c - d  muestra el valor dela seleccionado  abajo  "buen dia"      y en otro lado de la misma página    otras opciones  l - ll - lll - lV - V  y muestra un texto de una de estas opciones ,la seleccionada,abajo del listado por ejemplo "casa" en vez de id=para que pongo aquí para situar este texto . Lo mismo con el ejemplo anterior donde puse "buen dia"

Answer (score 0):

Puedes seleccionar varios Ids de la siguiente forma

```
$("#ID1,#ID2,#ID3")....
```

separandolas con ","

pero te recomiendo que lo hagas con clases, salduos

Comment: Hola. Y los tres id para ubicar los tres textos correspondientes?

Comment: los textos provienen de un back ?

Comment: No, de cada <input    value="Hola">

Comment: utiliza el "this" para obtenerlos

Comment: Hola Alberto, entiendo que eso es lo que resuelve mi consulta. Me ocuparé de ponerlo en práctica.  Gracias